# How to use external libraries with virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, apache-spark

I'm trying to figure out how to use external libraries. I have a program that runs successfully on Spark, and I am now trying to import external libraries. I'm using `virtualenv` and every time I submit it, spark complains that it cannot find the file.

Here is one of many submit commands I have tried:

```
/path/to/spark-1.1.0-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/spark-submit ua_analysis.py --py-files `pwd`/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I have tried adding the files individually with the `--py-files` flag, I've also tried the following subdirectories.

```
venv/lib
venv/python2.7
venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/<package_name>
```

All of these produce the following error

```
ImportError: ('No module named <module>', <function subimport at 0x7f287255dc80>, (<module>,))

    org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:124)
    org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:154)
    org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:87)
....
```

I've also tried copying these files to the `pyspark` directory to no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you create virtual env, pass `--system-site-packages` option to `virtualenv`:

```
virtualenv --system-site-packages venv
```

If you forgot pass the option:

```
rm venv/lib/python2.7/no-global-site-packages.txt
```

By both ways, you can `import system-site-packages` in the virtual env.

Answer (score 1):

not sure the answer above is still valid in my case add to modify:

`include-system-site-packages = false` to `include-system-site-packages = true`

in my `pyvenv.cfg` file that is located in my specific virtualenv (i.e 'virtaulenv_number_1' folder. Now I can use libraries not present in my virtualenv but presents in the sytem wide python installation